# issue selecting the child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html

```
<div class="sez-form">
    <table><input></table>
</div>
```

That can become

```
<div class="sez-form">
    <table><input></table>
    <div class="previsione"></div>
</div>
```

I am checking if previsione exists but this code:

```
$(document).on('blur','.importo',function(){
    var input_value = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).closest('.sez-form').next('.previsioni').length != null) {
        $('.previsioni').html('Qui le singole previsioni '+input_value);
        console.log('exists');
    }else{
        $(this).closest('.sez-form').append('<div class="previsioni">Qui le singole previsioni '+input_value+'</div>');         
    }
});
```

always return "exists" in console.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried as many options as I know to identify the child previsioni div but with no luck

Comment: FYI the `length` property will never be `null` - it's an integer value.

Comment: `<table><input></table>` That's invalid HTML markup...

Comment: @A.Wolff yes. It was just to show what the DOM structure is

Comment: @LelioFaieta oops ya sorry, i see it now what you meant. But what is `.importo`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) or [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) as `previsioni` is child of `sez-form` element. Also as `.length` returns you number it will never be `null`, use the property directly.

```
if ($(this).closest('.sez-form').find('.previsioni').length) {
   console.log('exists');
}
```

Comment: you are right. I tried your code but with length != null that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

compare using this

```
if ($(this).closest('.sez-form').find('.previsioni').length != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly that's a wrong layout, and the browsers will try to fill in `<tr>` and `<td>` for you. It is always better to use the right one:

```
<div class="sez-form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now here, let's add something:

```
$(".sez-form").append('<div class="previsione"></div>');
```

This now looks like:

```
<div class="sez-form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="previsione"></div>
</div>
```

And to get the `.html()`, you can use either:

```
$(".previsione").html();
```

Or, you can use:

```
$("input").closest(".sez-form").find(".previsione");
```